# Noda Time (C#) Magic to parse JSON (supposed ISO 8601) Date. e.g. 1396949418557

Tags: c#, nodatime

I cannot for the life of me deserialize a date string which I am told is ISO 8601 (e.g. '1396949418557') to a C# DateTime object.

I really like what I've read about Noda Time, and I am using JSON.NET. Has anyone come across this?

Comment: That is not a 8601 date.  The year would be 1396, so maybe, then the month would be 94, which is of course incorrect...

Comment: I stared at it and could not map that value to anything that could (with any format) resemble the current date, but I was told emphatically that it was an ISO 8601 date so I thought I was missing something. Now I have confirmation. ;)  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a unix timestamp. Try this:

```
var unixEraStart = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var dateTime = unixEraStart.AddMilliseconds(1396949418557);
```

Comment: Thank you *very much* That was the answer. The value didn't appear to resemble an 8601 date/time string to me, but I thought I could be missing something. Now, it works *and* I'm going to provide some candid feedback to some folks. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Using Noda Time:

```
Instant instant = Instant.FromMillisecondsSinceUnixEpoch(1396949418557);
```

Comment: Right on the nail, thank you! In fact, double thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your string looks like a Javascript timestamp (milliseconds since 1970/01/01, effectively 1000 * unix time).

I've never used nodatime, but it looks like that library defines time in terms of ticks since the unix epoch, with 10,000 ticks = 1 millisecond. So if you do an Int64.Parse of your string, then multiply it by 10,000, you should be able to construct a nodatime date object with that value.

Comment: Thank you! This added bit is necessary for anyone viewing this post because of course date time, et al, doesn't take a string!